# The method setUI(ScrollBarUI) in the type JScrollBar is not applicable for the arguments (LayoutScrollPane)

Tags: java

The method setUI(ScrollBarUI) in the type JScrollBar is not applicable for the arguments (LayoutScrollPane)

```
private void addDebugArea() {
      debug_area = new LayoutTextArea(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(),
           Color.decode("#4A4A4A"), Color.white, "Roboto-Regular.ttf", 12);
      JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(debug_area, 20, 31);

      scroller.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new LayoutScrollPane(Color.decode("#F3F4F4")));
      //                              ^^^^^

      scroller.getVerticalScrollBar()
           .setPreferredSize(new Dimension(7, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
      this.add(scroller);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's much better if you share your non-working code as a minimal reproducible example so that the proposed solution actually applies to your problem and can help future visitors with the same problem. Otherwise, there's a high likelihood that people will be tossing out random solutions that might not help you (or anyone else) much. See How to Ask and take the tour for more information on how to ask an on-topic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.setUI(new LayoutScrollPane(Color.decode("#F3F4F4")));`

It seems that you are trying to use a `setUI` method that accepts a `ScrollBarUI` and not the `LayoutScrollPane`  you are attempting to pass on as an argument.

Fix this by creating a `new ScrollBarUI` and passing it on as an argument instead.